# Change interval multipling it by a number inside an array using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I want to modify the timing at which console.log(prevIndex) is displayed by adjusting the speed array using currentLocationIndex to iterate over [1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4]. The current code does not produce the expected behavior. Thanks in advance for any assistance from those willing to help.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState([1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4]);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState([10, 20, 13, 20, 10, 2]);
  const [currentLocationIndex, setCurrentLocationIndex] = useState(0);

  function updateLocation() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentLocationIndex((prevIndex) => {
        console.log(prevIndex);
        if (prevIndex < location.length - 1) {
          console.log(prevIndex);
          return prevIndex + 1;
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval);
          return prevIndex;
        }
      });
    }, 1000 * speed[currentLocationIndex]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={updateLocation}>Initiate</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I was expecting that the time interval would change with this line of code:

```
1000 * speed[currentLocationIndex])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is the `currentLocationIndex`  remains the same due to the function `updateLocation` staying the same while the rest of the component is getting updated during the rerender, that's why the `currentLocationIndex` always stays at the first index value (`1` in your case).

Now that we have identified the problem, we can start solution it. To get the updated state `currentLocationIndex`, we should do it the React way -- `useEffect`, so when the component is re-rendered, the `currentLocationIndex` will get updated as well instead of still using the staled value.

Also, instead of using `setInterval` (which is the culprit of staled value), we will use `setTimeout`, and add the `currentLocationIndex` as dependency for `useHook` so the `setTimer` will be triggered after the `currentLocationIndex` is updated, effectively mimicking the `setInterval`.

Below is the implementation

```
// additional variable for the toggle state
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if (!toggle) {
    if (currentLocationIndex !== 0) {
      // if previously toggled, reset the state
      clearTimeout(timeoutInstance)
      setCurrentLocationIndex(0)
      console.log('Timeout Stopped/Cleared')
    }
    return
  }

  // store this in a global variable so it can still be used outside of useEffect block
  timeoutInstance = setTimeout(() => {
    setCurrentLocationIndex((prevIndex) => {
      console.log(prevIndex)
      if (prevIndex < location.length - 1) {
        console.log(prevIndex)
        return prevIndex + 1
      } else {
        setToggle(false)
        return prevIndex
      }
    })
  }, 1000 * speed[currentLocationIndex])

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutInstance) // make sure to clean up
  }
}, [toggle, currentLocationIndex])
```

Full implementation here: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-dew-vkmqd7?file=/src/App.tsx